# Does pinging the page on social bookmarking sites whre your site has been bookmarked help SEO?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

If you bookmark your site on say, delicious, does it help to then ping the url on delicious that contains the bookmark to your site?

Answer (score 2):

No. Not only do the search engines not have this data to work with but it is so easy to manipulate that if they did have it they couldn't trust it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean. They don't have what data?

Comment: They don't know how much traffic or pings a page gets on another website. They don't have access to that site's data. Without it they can't know that kind of information.

Comment: I'm just talking about pinging the page once with something like pingler.com to help google notice there's a new link to my site

Comment: It's unnecessary. If Google can crawl the site with the link then they'll find the link just as easy, if not easier, then finding the link through a third party site. And in the case of social bookmarking sites they almost always use nofollow so those links have no SEO value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Does pinging the page on social
>   bookmarking sites whre your site has
>   been bookmarked help SEO?

If I understand correctly, you want to know whether links to your content from a blog syndication site, (i.e. blogcatalog.com) created when you use a service like pingler will increase the likelihood that your new content will be spidered by search engines - to that, I would say that links from reputable websites won't *hurt*.

The way your question is worded, however, suggests that you are asking whether registering a [pingback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) to a bookmark-tracking site when the bookmarking site links to your content is a good idea and I think this is where John Conde is suggesting that the suggested activity is not productive - issuing a pingback to a bookmarking site would essentially create [spurious metadata](http://www.well.com/~doctorow/metacrap.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly yes. Pinging the site might help it being featured more openly (recent updates, news, newest sites...) which in turn means that when a search engine indexes the bookmarking site there's higher probability it will encounter a link to your site.

Answer (score -1):

well on my experience, then yes! it helps seo as you'll get backlinks from it

every link i did on my page to get a higher rank i usually do it with

- digg.com
- twitter.com
- delicous.com
- linkarena.com
- stumbleupon.com

with that strategy - my links ended up on first page rank 1-8

Comment: You were so busy spamming this site you didn't notice most if not all of those site use nofollow on their links so they have no SEO value.